# Cleaning out AD Roaming Profile Cache

Tags: windows, cache, active-directory, users, roaming-profiles

I've been playing around with AD RPs after watching some videos and they mentioned that you end up with a lot of disk space being filled due to cache and files being copied over from the server where they are kept.

Is there a script or tool like CCleaner that could automatically clean and remove said cache/files so that there is always space?